# SqlAdapter.Update() method perform insertion instead of updation

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I used SqlAdapter.Update() method to update the rows in a table.
For that I created Datatable and add values to that datatable.

```
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable("Product");
SqlConnection myLocalConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from " + dtTable.TableName, myLocalConnection);
SqlCommandBuilder mySqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);

 mySqlDataAdapter.Update(dtTable);
```

When I using this command it insert new rows in the database rather than updating the existing rows. Why does this happen?

Comment: Where is PrimaryKey of that table that you want to update ?

Comment: @Jignesh.Raj there is three coulmns ID,NAME,PRICE. here ID is the primary key..

Comment: In Your Query I think dtTable Has No Row Can you check that?

Comment: @Jignesh.Raj I checked that . It have all the rows. This row inserted in the database rather than updating existing.. that is the problem.. No problem with datatable.

Comment: @folk You've just made a new data table. It has no rows? I'm assuming you're showing us pseudo-code. Check that the data table's rows have a reasonable status. [That is to say, they should be `Modified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww3k31w0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ta.speot.is Exectlly I want to tell that

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea and not the solution...

```
// update command to update database table. 
string strUpdateCommand =
"Update Students set Name = @Name, Gender = @Gender, Total = @Total where ID = @ID";
// create an instance of SqlCommand using the update command created above. 
SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(strUpdateCommand, con);
// specify the paramaters of the update command. 
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name");
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20, "Gender");
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Total");
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ID");
// associate update command with SqlDataAdapter instance. 
dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = updateCommand;
```

Comment: how? will you please explain?

Comment: What is this? I am using SqlAdapter Update() method. Please Read my question.

Comment: In this case I used SqlAdapter/Dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening here is (As per your given code) your dataadapter is unable to recognize rows in your datatable it is nowhere related to your datatable here, So as a guess try to fill your datatable via dataadapter then modify your datatable and update it.

```
    DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection myLocalConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);

    SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from " +   
    dtTable.TableName, myLocalConnection); 

    SqlCommandBuilder builder= new SqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);     
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dtTable,"Products" ) 

     // Code to modify your datatable

    mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();  

    mySqlDataAdapter.Update(dtTable);
```

-- Hope it helps .